# Listen Click event on a row of ListGrid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Is that possible to listen click event on a row of a ListGrid ? If yes, how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Manu Alternatively you can do the following:

```
listGrid.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
            // your code
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListGridField[] listGridFields = listGrid.getFields();
for (ListGridField listGridField : listGridFields) {

  listGridField.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
      evaluator.recordClicked(event.getRecord());
    }
  });

}
```

Is there a better way to do that ?